# "The Object you want to instantiate is null" But I'm using an asset of unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are tons of questions like this but none of them seem to apply to me since I am directly using an asset from Unity. I have a Bullet prefab set to Rigidbody2D and has the tag "Bullet".

When I put

Here is my source code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Umbrella : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Bullet bullet;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {            
            Instantiate(bullet);
        }

    }
}
```

I have bullet tagged and everything, yet it doesn't work.
[image]

I've literally been stuck on this for nearly an hour now...

EDIT:
[image: Umbrella]

Comment: Please edit the question to include an image of the inspector showing the `Umbrella` component.  I'm guessing you have no `Bullet` assigned to it.

Comment: @Ruzihm Just did

Comment: Drag the prefab into where it says `Bullet None (Rain)`

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks SO MUCH. I knew it was something simple when I realized no one else had this type of error with instantiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your Bullet prefab to the `bullet` member of the Umbrella component so that when it calls `Instantiate(bullet);` it knows what `bullet` should be.

You can do this by dragging the prefab into where it says <kbd>Bullet None (Rain)</kbd> as shown below:
[image]